# Does Spring (Boot) have a special treatment for package-names .model and .repo?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a @SpringBootTest that autowires a @Repository which returns an @Entity. I have no specific ComponentScanning declared.

This works as long as the Repo is in a package my.repo and the entity and test are in package my.model

If I move all three to package my.repo I get "Not a managed type" for the model.
If I move all three to package my.model I get "No qualifying bean of type" for the repo.

I know about the recommended package structure. But is it more than a recommendation? Are there strict rules for the packages hardcoded?

Comment: No there isn't. Assuming you are using Spring Data JPA I suspect you have an `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` somewhere which you didn't change while moving the classes. You probably have those because you dont' follow the recommended packaging.

Comment: Yes you were right! It turned out to be a project handling two datasources. I found `@Configuration` classes containing `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `em.setPackagesToScan(...)`. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

As long as your `@Repository` is in the same package with other classes/entities, it doesnt need any scanning. But yes if you choose to use a different package, you must tell spring to scan your specific packages for your `@Repositoy`(ies). So somewhere in your `@Configuration` class, use this:

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "someuniq.packagename.goeshere")`.

For an example - like [this](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/config/ConfigWebSecurity.java).